# Is there a way to display all screens in a single screen in React Native

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

I am working on a project where I am using multiple WebViews. Its like a browser app. The problem is that I want to create a tabview where I can show all the WebViews in a single screen. You can understand it just like chrome tabview from where I can add new tabs and remove older ones. I have googled it but cannot find a relevant answer.

Is there any way to do that.

Just like this one..

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now, none of the current navigation libraries in `react-native` provide such functionality.
So the only way you can achieve this is to track your tabs on your own and in case the user wants to see all of them you should open a scrollable modal and show all available tabs to her.
And as she clicks on one of them you navigate her to that specific screen or component.